# Delay in scheduling interviews

Tags: interviewing, applications, email

I applied for a software position in a large, reputed company and was contacted to schedule phone interviews. They asked me to provide a few dates over the next 3 weeks so that they could schedule these interviews. I followed up with them after a week of no response, and they told me they would get back to me with a save-the-date email as soon as possible. I followed up with them again after 3 weeks, and even provided a bunch of new dates.

Meanwhile, I am also applying to other companies, and have had interviews or have interviews scheduled with them. However, I am particularly keen on interviewing with the company I mentioned earlier. I am worried that the interviews may not be scheduled in time, and I may have to accept another offer if it is delayed a lot.

I did mention in the initial e-mail that I am actively looking for jobs. However, I did not have any interviews scheduled at that particular time, so I did not think it was necessary to mention them.

Is there a way in which I could push for these interviews to be scheduled soon, without seeming rude or inconsiderate? I understand that it is of low priority to them, but I do not want to lose this opportunity.

Comment: So, basically, 4 weeks have passed and you are still to get an email confirming the phone interview? Even after asking and following up 2 times?

Comment: @DarkCygnus Yes. Is that a bad sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They blew you off twice already. The recruiter is probably overwhelmed and not very organized, so you fell through the cracks.

If you're in a rush, then **it's time to light a fire under them.**

> Hi Recruiter X,
>   I'd just like to follow up one more time to see if Company Z is still interested in moving forward in the recruiting process. As I mentioned in my initial email, I'm currently actively seeking other employment and am moving forward with several other companies at this time. However, the position Y with Company Z is still one of the positions I am most interested in, so I hope our timelines match up!

---

The fact that you fell through the cracks is probably not a good sign. It's entirely possible that they just let you go.

If you're in a rush to move forward, them moving on should be totally fine with you. At least you know not to wait for them.
If you don't actually have a reason to rush (ie other offers/companies that you are in the advanced stages with), then you may be better off just waiting patiently.

Comment: Thank you! This actually worked! I sent the recruiter an email a day before my interview with another company, and she followed up within the next 2 days with a schedule. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2522981 Glad to hear that it worked out

Answer (score 4):

> I applied for a software position in a large, reputed company...

Very large companies tend to have clunky HR departments.

> Is there a way in which I could push for these interviews to be
>   scheduled soon, without seeming rude or inconsiderate? I understand
>   that it is of low priority to them, but I do not want to lose this
>   opportunity.

Do you know or have contact with someone who isn't in HR?  A hiring manager would be ideal, they're the ones who have the incentive to hire someone and they're also the ones with the budget and can push on HR.  HR is often a serious bottleneck.  It's annoying and counter productive from the manager's point of view if HR is so slow that they lose people, but the only thing he can really do is push on them one candidate at a time.

If you don't know of someone, then reach out and poke HR once a day until you get some sort of timeline.  Let them know the clock is ticking and you're starting to get other offers.

Comment: The recruiter is essentially blaming the hiring manager. She says she is waiting for information from the hiring manager to schedule interviews. I did ask the employee who referred me to the company for help, but I can't be sure if that will really make a difference.

Comment: @user2522981 Ask if you can have a phone interview with him and/or his group.  That won't reduce the number of hoops you still need to go through, but it might speed things up.  It might also give you useful names.

Answer (score 0):

> I am worried that the interviews may not be scheduled in time, and I may have to accept another offer if it is delayed a lot.

This I must say is a natural part of job-hunting.

Some offers may come earlier, and some may come late. The "art" of job-hunting is to navigate and balance these offers and dates, so you obtain the best outcome possible.

There may be times where you will have to decide if you are willing to decline an offer in favor of waiting for the possibility of another.

> Is there a way in which I could push for these interviews to be scheduled soon, without seeming rude or inconsiderate? I understand that it is of low priority to them, but I do not want to lose this opportunity.

You already followed-up 2 times now, and even provided more possible dates.

I don't think there is more you can to to graciously speed their response time. At best seems you will be wasting time/effort in an attempt that you have still no response (and that you could invest elsewhere).

Seems to me that this is one of those times where you will have to decide if you are willing to decline other offers in favor of a chance with this one.